# OnMainThreadException error, though there is no Network action performed on main thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, exception, asynchronous, program-entry-point

so I am making an app, I am just beginner, but I am stuck, I have this code:

```
public class MenuChoice extends Activity {
    InputStream string = null;
    ArrayList<String> Deals = null;
    ArrayList<String> ImageBase;
    int currentDeal = 0;

    public void StreamReader() throws IOException{
        InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(string);
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(is);
        String read = br.readLine();

        while(read != null) {
            //System.out.println(read);
            sb.append(read);
            read =br.readLine();

        }
        String[] DealList = sb.toString().split("±");
        //ArrayList<String> deals = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 0; i < DealList.length; i++){
            Log.d("msgs", DealList[i]);
            if(DealList[i].length() > 5){
                Deals.add(DealList[i]);
            }
        }
//      return deals;
    }
    public String DownloadImg(String urla, String newname){
        String fileName = null;
        try{
        URL url = new URL (urla);
        InputStream input = url.openStream();
        try {
        //The sdcard directory e.g. '/sdcard' can be used directly, or 
        //more safely abstracted with getExternalStorageDirectory()
        File storagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream (storagePath + "/" + newname + "/.png");
        fileName = storagePath + "/" + newname + "/.png";
        try {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[5000];
            int bytesRead = 0;
            while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) >= 0) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        } finally {
            output.close();
        }
        } finally {
        input.close();
        }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        }

        return fileName;
    }
    public void SetInp(InputStream inp){
        string = inp;
    }

    public class GetDeals extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            InputStream str = null;
            HttpClient htc = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost htp = new HttpPost("site/android_connect.php");
                try {
                    HttpEntity resp = htc.execute(htp).getEntity();
                    InputStream strings = resp.getContent();
                    str = strings;
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    Log.d("problema" ,"BAD!");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d("problema" ,"BAD!");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            string = str;
            return null;

    }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_choice);

        try {
            new GetDeals().execute().get();
        }
        catch(Exception e){}
        /*    try {
            Deals = StreamReader(string);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        /*
        for(int i = 0; i<Deals.size(); i++){

            ImageBase.add(DownloadImg(Deals.get(i), "Deal"+i));
            Log.d("bugger", DownloadImg(Deals.get(i), "Deal"+i));
        }
        */
        try {
            StreamReader();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_choice, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

so I get this error thrown:

> 08-26 17:42:52.030: E/AndroidRuntime(10221): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   08-26 17:42:52.030: E/AndroidRuntime(10221):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{plugMedia.kcrarea/plugMedia.kcrarea.MenuChoice}:
>   android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException 08-26 17:42:52.030:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(10221):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
>   08-26 17:42:52.030: E/AndroidRuntime(10221):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
>   08-26 17:42:52.030: E/AndroidRuntime(10221):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123) 08-26
>   17:42:52.030: E/AndroidRuntime(10221):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
>   08-26 17:42:52.030: E/AndroidRuntime(10221):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 08-26
>   17:42:52.030: E/AndroidRuntime(10221):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 08-26 17:42:52.030:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(10221):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424) 08-26
>   17:42:52.030: E/AndroidRuntime(10221):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 08-26
>   17:42:52.030: E/AndroidRuntime(10221):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 08-26 17:42:52.030:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(10221):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
>   08-26 17:42:52.030: E/AndroidRuntime(10221):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554) 08-26
>   17:42:52.030: E/AndroidRuntime(10221):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 08-26 17:42:52.030:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(10221): Caused by:
>   android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException 08-26 17:42:52.030:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(10221):  at
>   android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
>   08-26 17:42:52.030: E/AndroidRuntime(10221):  at
>   libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:163) 08-26
>   17:42:52.030: E/AndroidRuntime(10221):    at
>   libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:503) 08-26 17:42:52.030:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(10221):  at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:488) 08-26
>   17:42:52.030: E/AndroidRuntime(10221):    at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46) 08-26
>   17:42:52.030: E/AndroidRuntime(10221):    at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)
>   08-26 17:42:52.030: E/AndroidRuntime(10221):  at
>   org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:103)
>   08-26 17:42:52.030: E/AndroidRuntime(10221):  at
>   org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.read(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:120)
>   08-26 17:42:52.030: E/AndroidRuntime(10221):  at
>   org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.getChunkSize(ChunkedInputStream.java:211)
>   08-26 17:42:52.030: E/AndroidRuntime(10221):  at
>   org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.nextChunk(ChunkedInputStream.java:183)
>   08-26 17:42:52.030: E/AndroidRuntime(10221):  at
>   org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:155)
>   08-26 17:42:52.030: E/AndroidRuntime(10221):  at
>   org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:159)
>   08-26 17:42:52.030: E/AndroidRuntime(10221):  at
>   java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:244) 08-26
>   17:42:52.030: E/AndroidRuntime(10221):    at
>   java.io.BufferedReader.fillBuf(BufferedReader.java:130) 08-26
>   17:42:52.030: E/AndroidRuntime(10221):    at
>   java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:390) 08-26
>   17:42:52.030: E/AndroidRuntime(10221):    at
>   plugMedia.kcrarea.MenuChoice.StreamReader(MenuChoice.java:59) 08-26
>   17:42:52.030: E/AndroidRuntime(10221):    at
>   plugMedia.kcrarea.MenuChoice.onCreate(MenuChoice.java:158) 08-26
>   17:42:52.030: E/AndroidRuntime(10221):    at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465) 08-26
>   17:42:52.030: E/AndroidRuntime(10221):    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
>   08-26 17:42:52.030: E/AndroidRuntime(10221):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
>   08-26 17:42:52.030: E/AndroidRuntime(10221):  ... 11 more

I understand it's saying that I am trying to perform Network action on main thread, but all I am doing is calling StreamReader which I assume just converts InputStream (saved and retrieved from AsyncTask but it throws error.

Any help? What's causing it?

Thank you.

Comment: You are doing NetworkRelated operation on the main ui thread which is not possible post honeycomb.

You can use `threads` or asynctask

Comment: Raghunandan - What networkrelated operation am I running? I thought my only NetworkRelated operation is in AsyncTask and nowhere else?

Comment: Also I do have permission added in manifest for INTERNET ACCESS

Comment: you are doing this `new GetDeals().execute().get()` should be `new GetDeals().execute()`

Comment: But if I remove .get() it doesn't set the InputSream string = null to the InputStream it gets from link. While if I add .get() it does set it, so I thought I need to have .get()

Comment: You need to remove get. calling the `get()` method of AsyncTask will block the main thread and wait for the result to be returned. This effectively makes using an AsyncTask become a synchronous operation in which case there's no point in using an AsyncTask.

Comment: Oh, okay I understand now, but that brings new problem in: Why does my AsyncTask not set the InputStream it gets from .php file and sets it to InputStream string ? Or is there any specific way to return results from AsyncTask?

Comment: you can have a class member and then assign the same in asynctask

Comment: Okay, thank you Raghunandan for explaining me what was causing the error, I will work on fixing it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But if I remove .get() it doesn't set the InputSream string = null to the InputStream it gets from link.

Move your use of the `InputStream` and its results (e.g., your `StreamReader()` call) to `onPostExecute()` of the `AsyncTask`, and remove the call to `get()`. As Raghunandan points out, `get()` basically means that there was no point in having the `AsyncTask` in the first place, which is why I have [an outstanding feature request to get a Lint warning added for this](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57457).

Comment: Thank you CommonsWare, guess I will for start learn more about AsyncTask and then fix my problem.

Comment: wow wtf, i've never even seen `.get()` ever before. `AsyncTask` is supposed to make "easy threading" according to Android docs. when i first read about threading i would definitely not know the implications of `get()`... horrible horrible design